# Python distutils.Extension : setting a concurrency level

Tags: python, concurrency, distutils

I'm wondering how to reproduce the equivalent of a `make -j<n>` on a setup.py using distutils.Extension, in order to build a C extension to Python 2.6 .

My desired outcome: having `setup.py build` using a few instances of my C-compiler in the same time, instead of only one.

There are probably an environnement var or two that I'm missing.

Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And [the answer from distutils-sig's mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2010-July/016639.html) is : a patch for distutils2 is still to be written.